# Post Content - Foreach/loop tagged users

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am trying to setup notifications on forum posts / threads and have come up with the following:

```
    $usertag = strstr($post, '@');
$usertag = str_replace('@', '', $usertag);
$tagquery = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='{$usertag}'" );
$tagarray = $db->assoc( $tagquery );
$tagcount = $db->num( $tagquery );
if($tagcount==1){
$tagid = $tagarray['id'];
echo $usertag;
}
```

The problem is I don't think this would loop itself for multiple usernames.

example post content:

> I would like to thank @username1 and @username2 for all their help!

Any help on helping me achieve this would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP explode will work, could be wrong - put the above down to it being late.